# Twitch API - follow a user, getting "411 Length Required" error

Tags: php, api, curl, oauth-2.0, twitch

So i'm writing a function for a client whom wants a simple function to use on his social site so that users can follow channel on Twitch, no SDKs nothing like that i have the following function:

```
function twitch_follow_channel($user, $channel, $client_id, $access_token) {

      $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/'.$user.'/follows/channels/'.$channel.'?oauth_token='.$access_token);  
            $h = 'Client-ID: '.$client_id.', Accept: application/vnd.twitchtv.v3+json, Authorization: OAuth '. $access_token;
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: OAuth '.$access_token,
                                                       'Client-ID: '.$client_id,
                                                       'Content-Length: '.strlen($h), 
                                                       'Accept: application/vnd.twitchtv.v3+json'));    
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0); 
      $r  = curl_exec($ch);
      $ci = curl_getinfo($ch);
      r($ci);
      r($r);
      return json_decode($r, true);       

}
```

i include the `Content-length` in the HTTP HEADER i don't know what i'm missing

[image]

[image]

### Notes

- The access token has `user_follows_edit` scope.
- `r()` is used instead of `var_dump()`
- I'm already aware of the [**DOCs**](https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/blob/master/v3_resources/follows.md#put-usersuserfollowschannelstarge) at GitHub, followed it carefully

Answer (score 0):

Recently did that myself so how about you add:

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
```

This way you say CURL to use PUT as request.

To unfollow simply replace PUT with DELETE and your gucci.

Atom8tik